# Using parameters in rails json :include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

```
def class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
    has_one :user_answer, -> (uid) { where(user_id: uid) }
end

@question = Question.find(5)
@question.to_json(:include => user_answer(2) )
```

In the above example I have an association that expects a parameter. How can I include this association in a json include with the parameter?

I have solved the issue using an instance variable, but it's annoying. I'd like to find a better solution. This is not the same example, but a simpler one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a scope instead of the has_one:

```
def class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  scope :user_answers, -> (uid) { where(user_id: uid) }
end

@questions = Question.user_answers(user_id).limit(5)
@questions = @questions.to_json
```

Comment: My use case is more complex. There are nested associations and I wanted to pass parameters to an association of and association. I should have used the more complex example. This answer is correct for this example.